# JComboBox from ArrayList<String> - Not working - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, arraylist

I am still playing with Java and swing (still quite new to it all).  I am trying to populate a JComboBox with the data from a .txt file.  I am pulling the data into an ArrayList and am attempting to populate the JComboBox with the ArrayList variable.  The combobox is blank when I run the application however.

This is the Array Code:

```
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

File Reader Code:

```
private void fileRead(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Examiner.txt"));
            // ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             while(scan.hasNext()){
                 list.add(scan.next());
             }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
```

And the mess I am using for my comboboxes:

```
 private void comboBoxes(){                
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
        String[] comboBox1Array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTeachedCourses);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }
```

Entire mess of code for this class.

```
package messing with swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;


public class ReportGUI extends JFrame{
    //Fields
    private JButton viewAllReports = new JButton("View All Program Details");
    private JButton viewPrograms = new JButton("View Programs and Majors Associated with this course"); 
    private JButton viewTeachedCourses = new JButton("View Courses this Examiner Teaches"); 
    private JLabel courseLabel = new JLabel("Select a Course: ");
    private JLabel examinerLabel = new JLabel("Select an Examiner: "); 
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,2,4,4));  
    private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //private String storeAllString="";



     public ReportGUI(){   
       reportInterface();
       allReportsBtn();     
       comboBoxes();
       fileRead();
     }   



     private void fileRead(){
         try{
             Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Examiner.txt"));
            // ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
             while(scan.hasNext()){
                 list.add(scan.next());
             }
             scan.close();
         }
         catch (FileNotFoundException e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }

    private void reportInterface(){         
          setTitle("Choose Report Specifications");                   
          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
          JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
          add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
          setSize(650,200);
          setVisible(true);    
          setResizable(false);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}    
    private void allReportsBtn(){
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,1)); 
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(70, 50, 70, 25));
        panel.add(viewAllReports);        
        viewAllReports.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFrame AllDataGUI = new JFrame();
                new AllDataGUI();
            }
        });         
        add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }       
    private void comboBoxes(){                
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 5, 5, 10));
        String[] comboBox1Array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array);          
        panel.add(examinerLabel);
        panel.add(comboBox1);          
        panel.add(viewTeachedCourses);
         JComboBox comboBox2 = new JComboBox();
         panel.add(courseLabel);         
         panel.add(comboBox2); 
         panel.add(viewPrograms);
         add(panel, BorderLayout.LINE_START); 

    }      







}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you sure `list` contains anything?  Also, what layout manager is `panel` using?

Comment: We meet again Mad:P  I will post the entire class above.  It is embarrassing and I am now so don't flame too hard.

Comment: @Splunk where are you adding the list to the comboBox ??!!

Comment: @Amir `JComboBox comboBox1 = new JComboBox(comboBox1Array); ` after it's converted to an array of `String` ;)

Comment: Well, you also populate the list *after* it has been added to the combobox.

Comment: @Obicere I'm not sure I know what you mean.

Comment: @Splunk you copy the elements to an array, which is done before the file is ever read. Call `fileRead()` before calling `comboBoxes()` in the `ReportGUI` constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 public ReportGUI()
 {   
   reportInterface();
   allReportsBtn();     
   comboBoxes();
   fileRead();
 }
```

As Obicere has pointed out:

1. you first invoke `comboBoxes()`, which creates the combo boxes and populates the combo box with an empty List.
2. then you invoke the `fileRead()` method which adds the data to the List, but this does NOT update the model of the combo box.

The code order needs to be reversed:

```
fileRead();
comboBoxes();
```

Comment: Long day. Couldn't be arsed to write up all that text haha. Good gob man

Answer (score 2):

Taka close look at the order you are doing thins...

```
public ReportGUI(){   
   reportInterface();
   allReportsBtn();     
   comboBoxes();
   fileRead();
 }
```

First, you call `reportInterface`, which initialises your frame...

Second, you call `allReportsBtn`, which creates your buttons...

Third, you call `comboBoxes`, which applies the contents of the `List` to your combo box, which is empty...

Fourth, you call `fileRead`, which reads the values from the file...

There is no relationship between the array you supplied to the `JComboBox` or the `List` of values you read of the file, so even if you told the combobox that the values had changed, it would not see that change

Try doing something more like

```
public ReportGUI(){   
   reportInterface();
   allReportsBtn();     
   fileRead();
   comboBoxes();
 }
```

instead...

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I honestly didn't know that the order in which you called methods mattered.  Thanks guys.

Comment: It kind of does and it kind of doesn't, what matters here is that the relationship between the component and the `List` doesn't exist, so even when you update the `List`, there's simply no way for the component to know that it's changed or see those changes.

Comment: @Splunk Could you do me a favour, technically camickr answered first and our answers are pretty much the same, if you can't find anything in my answer which helps you significantly more than his, could you mark his question as correct

Comment: For some reason now my combobox is only displaying one word.  For example instead of displaying Andrew Taylor on one line, it is displaying Andrew on one line then Taylor on the other.

Comment: @Splunk I'd imagine this will come down to how the file is parsed, instead of `scan.hasNext()` and `scan.next()`, you probably should be using `scan.hasNextLine()` and `scan.nextLine()` ;)

Comment: Beautiful.  I also marked it as answered by camickr as he got in a minute sooner than you :P